# Is there a way to have a Web Farm that serves two different application versions using IIS 7

Tags: iis

I have an ASP.NET application.  I want to be able to invsibly rollout new versions to our customers (all users logon).  I want an "old" site and a "new" site.

The user has one url.  Once they are authenticated, they are sent either to the "old" or the "new" site depending on their database version.

Is this possible with IIS 7?  How best to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm completely understanding the question but I'm going to make some assumptions.
I'm presuming users logon via forms authentication, and that determining the users database version is trivial?

If so then you can simply host your old and new version in separate virtual directories
then make sure they can [share authentication cookies](http://aspalliance.com/901_How_To_Share_Authentication_Cookies_across_ASPNET_V11_and_ASPNET_V20_Applications). Once the user is successfully verified ( presumably on the new version of the site) if they should be using the old site you redirect them to the default page of that site instead of the new version. I believe the mehod to do the redirect in is RedirectFromLogonPage()

In addition to prevent the user from using a bookmark to go to the wrong site you could put something in the `Session_Start()` of `Global.asax` that does a lookup of the base URL the user should be using and redirect their request appropriately, you'd have to do that in both the new and OLD versions of the site though.

Comment: The problem is that will give me a different url, so if they bookmark they will have a different site.  I want the same url and switch of servers is not seen by user.

Comment: The initial URL will always be the same, (the logon page of the new app version of the app say <code>http://server/newversion</code>) so if that is bookmarked theres no problem. 

I see what you are saying though. If the user bookmarks mid session the url will be for the old version, <code>http://server/oldversion/somepage.aspx</code>.

I'll updated my answer with a suggestion..